# dhcpcd times out

Tags: networking

I've had a 3b+ running in headless mode for ages. I rebooted it last week, and it never came back online. It looks like dhcpcd is failing to start. I figured I might have misconfigured something, so I reinstalled Raspbian Lite. No good. Several sd cards, images, and a different pi later I still can't get dhcpcd to function. grepping syslog gives me:

```
Oct  9 12:33:42 raspberrypi dhcpcd[329]: eth0: soliciting a DHCP lease
Oct  9 12:33:43 raspberrypi dhcpcd[329]: eth0: Router Advertisement from [redacted]
Oct  9 12:33:43 raspberrypi dhcpcd[329]: eth0: zero length option
Oct  9 12:33:43 raspberrypi dhcpcd[329]: eth0: adding address [redacted]
Oct  9 12:33:43 raspberrypi dhcpcd[329]: eth0: adding route to [redacted]
Oct  9 12:33:43 raspberrypi dhcpcd[329]: eth0: adding default route via [redacted]
Oct  9 12:33:43 raspberrypi dhcpcd[329]: eth0: requesting DHCPv6 information
Oct  9 12:33:44 raspberrypi dhcpcd[329]: eth0: zero length option
Oct  9 12:35:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Oct  9 12:36:38 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: State 'stop-final-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Oct  9 12:36:38 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: Killing process 329 (dhcpcd) with signal SIGKILL.
Oct  9 12:36:38 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: Control process exited, code=killed status=9
Oct  9 12:36:38 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Oct  9 12:36:38 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct  9 12:36:38 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

Comment: Is the DHCP server on your network still running?

Comment: so, you get the same problem on multiple images and 2 different raspberry pi's? It's either your router (DHCP server) or you keep making the same (breaking) changes to some configuration that you aren't telling us about

Comment: Well at the time it *was* the DHCP server, but I've had to go back to letting the router handle that.

Comment: Jaromanda: no I'm using completely unaltered images. I don't think it's the router; for some strange reason NOOBS connects just fine.